# Laravel 9 vue with breeze and mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-breeze

`Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (2:0)
File was processed with these loaders:

```
./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import '../css/app.css';
| import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
```

I am getting this error on `npm run dev`